# Animate removing/adding SwiftUI view while animating offset

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to animate the offset of a SwiftUI view, while at the same time fading out and removing a subview of that view. The problem I'm running into is that SwiftUI performs the offset and fade-out animations, but doesn't combine them.

What I want to achieve to animate the position of the whole `SubView`, while simultaneously fading out the subtitle text, so that the subtitle text moves vertically while fading in or out. I can achieve this by animating the opacity of the `Text` instead of removing it, but that means the text will still take up "layout space".

Is there a way to achieve this animation with the `if showSubtitle` statement?

The following code and GIF demonstrate the problem:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSubtitle = true
    var body: some View {
        SubView(showSubtitle: showSubtitle)
            .animation(.default)
            .offset(y: showSubtitle ? 100 : 0)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showSubtitle.toggle()
            }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    let showSubtitle: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Header")
            if showSubtitle {
                Text("Subtitle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Video]

Comment: have you tried defining `showSubtitle`  as a `Binding` instead of a constant?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the observed behaviour is because `.offset` **does not** change layout, the view is stand at the same place. So when you remove subview it is removed *in-place* and animating that removal (with default `.opacity` transition). The part that starts *offsetting* does not contain already subview, so you don't see it in moving up part.

Here is something that might give some kind of effect you expect, but transitions are based on source size, so it is not so far and manually specified distance of offset. Anyway, try:

```
if showSubtitle {
    Text("Subtitle")
        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: AnyTransition.move(edge: .top)))
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

Comment: I don’t think it is because the offset not changing layout. I tried it with the `position` modifier, and the result is the same unfortunately. The `transition` workaround o kinda works, but it isn’t the most maintainable and flexible I think. Thanks for your answer though!